# Best way to indexing a matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

Let say, `A` and `B` are matrices of the same size.
In `Matlab`, I could use simple indexing as below.

```
idx = A>0;
B(idx) = 0
```

How can I do this in `OpenCV`? Should I just use

```
for (i=0; ... rows)
    for(j=0; ... cols)
        if (A.at<double>(i,j)>0) B.at<double>(i,j) = 0;
```

something like this? Is there a better (faster and more efficient) way?

Moreover, in `OpenCV`, when I try

```
Mat idx = A>0;
```

the variable `idx` seems to be a `CV_8U` matrix (not boolean but integer).

Comment: what do you mean by "best"? fastest? easiest to code? best to maintain? many functions use "masks" which are 8 bit input images that tell whether the pixel is "active" (non-zero) or "inactive" (zero). From a grayscale image you can easily create a mask by using for example `cv::Mat mask = A > 0`. For your example you could then use `B.setTo(cv::Scalar(0), mask)`

Comment: Thanks, Micka. I meant "faster and more efficient" by "better". I edited. Because I am a kind of Matlab guy, I was just hesitating over using the nested loops, and thinking another way to do it using some built-in functions  designed for faster implementation.

Comment: I'd suggest you do this in Python : B[A>0] = 0

Comment: How many channels has `B`? What's the typical size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily convert this MATLAB code:

```
idx = A > 0;
B(idx) = 0;

// same as 

B(A>0) = 0;
```

to OpenCV as:

```
Mat1d A(...)
Mat1d B(...)

Mat1b idx = A > 0;
B.setTo(0, idx) = 0;

// or

B.setTo(0, A > 0);
```

Regarding performance, in C++ it's usually faster (it depends on the enabled optimizations) to work on raw pointers (but is less *readable*):

```
for (int r = 0; r < B.rows; ++r)
{
    double* pA = A.ptr<double>(r);
    double* pB = B.ptr<double>(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < B.cols; ++c)
    {
        if (pA[c] > 0.0) pB[c] = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Also note that in OpenCV there isn't any *boolean* matrix, but it's a `CV_8UC1` matrix (aka a single channel matrix of `unsigned char`), where `0` means `false`, and any value `>0` is true (typically `255`).

**Evaluation**

Note that **this may vary** according to optimization enabled with OpenCV. You can test the code below on your PC to get accurate results.

Time in ms:

```
          my results           my results      @AdrienDescamps
          (OpenCV 3.0 No IPP)  (OpenCV 2.4.9)

Matlab  : 13.473     
C++ Mask: 640.824              5.81815         ~5
C++ Loop: 5.24414              4.95127         ~4
```

Note: I'm not entirely sure about the performance drop with OpenCV 3.0, so I just remark: **test the code below on your PC to get accurate results.**

As @AdrienDescamps stated in comments:

> It seems that the performance drop with OpenCV 3.0 is related to the OpenCL option, that is now enabled in the comparison operator.

**C++ Code**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    // Random initialize A with values in [-100, 100]
    Mat1d A(1000, 1000);
    randu(A, Scalar(-100), Scalar(100));

    // B initialized with some constant (5) value
    Mat1d B(A.rows, A.cols, 5.0); 

    // Operation: B(A>0) = 0;

    {
        // Using mask

        double tic = double(getTickCount());
        B.setTo(0, A > 0);
        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000 / getTickFrequency();

        cout << "Mask: " << toc << endl;
    }
    {
        // Using for loop

        double tic = double(getTickCount());
        for (int r = 0; r < B.rows; ++r)
        {
            double* pA = A.ptr<double>(r);
            double* pB = B.ptr<double>(r);
            for (int c = 0; c < B.cols; ++c)
            {
                if (pA[c] > 0.0) pB[c] = 0.0;
            }
        }
        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000 / getTickFrequency();

        cout << "Loop: " << toc << endl;
    }


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Matlab Code**

```
% Random initialize A with values in [-100, 100]
A = (rand(1000) * 200) - 100;
% B initialized with some constant (5) value
B = ones(1000) * 5; 

tic
B(A>0) = 0; 
toc
```

**UPDATE**

OpenCV 3.0 uses IPP optimization in the function `setTo`. If you have that enabled (you can check with `cv::getBuildInformation()`), you'll have a faster computation.

Comment: Are you sure about the time of the c++ mask? I get 5ms with opencv(2.4) compiled in Release mode and 9ms in Debug, for a c++ loop time of 4ms.

Comment: @AdrienDescamps this are the results I get, but I don't have much optimization enabled. As I mentioned, the results may vary (now bolded). I edited your results into the answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @AdrienDescamps actually with OpenCV 2.4.9 I get results same as yours. I was testing with OpenCV 3.0 without IPP enabled. I'm not sure about this performance drop, but it's just another argument for _"You can test the code below on your PC to get accurate results."_ Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It seems that the performance drop with OpenCV 3.0 is related to the OpenCL option, that is now enabled in the comparison operator.

Comment: @AdrienDescamps wierd that this causes such a performance drop... Many thanks for pointing that out! I have added your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The answer of Miki is very good, but i just want to add some clarification about the performance problem to avoid any confusion.

It is true that the best way to implement an image filter (or any algorithm) with OpenCV is to use the raw pointers, as shown in the second C++ example of Miki (C++ Loop). 
Using the at function is also correct, but significantly slower.

However, most of the time, you don't need to worry about that, and you can simply use the high level functions of OpenCV (first example of Miki , C++ Mask). They are well optimized, and will usually be almost as fast as a low level loop on pointers, or even faster.

Of course, there are exceptions (we just found one), and you should always test for your specific problem.

Now, regarding this specific problem :

The example here where the high level function was much slower (100x slower) than the low level loop is NOT a normal case, as it is demonstrated by the timings with other version/configuration of OpenCV, that are much lower.
The problem seems to be that when OpenCV3.0 is compiled with OpenCL, there is a huge overhead the first time a function that uses OpenCL is called. The simplest solution is to disable OpenCL at compile time, if you use OpenCV3.0 (see also [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/67592/opencv-30-vs-opencv-249-sobel-performance/) for other possible solutions if you are interested).

Comment: really helpful discussion