# How to efficiently extract certain pixels from cv::Mat image in C++?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am doing some image processing and I would like to extract certain pixel values from an gray-scale image. The pixels I want to extract are described with a mask array which has the same dimensions as gray-scale image.

This is very easily done in python using the numpy arrays. Example:

```py
pixels = img[mask != 0]
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do this in a efficient manner in C++ using opencv data type cv::Mat?

**Update**

I will provide a more extensive example to clarify my problem.
Let's assume I have a gray-scale image called *img* with dimensions (3,4). I also have a *mask* array with dimensions (3,4). I want to extract values from *img* array at position that correspond to position of non-zero values in *mask* array. 
If we assume the *mask* array has 4 non-zero elements, then 4 elements from *img* array need to be extracted (copied) into a new array called *pixels*.

```py
img = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
# img = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#              [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

mask = np.zeros_like(img)
mask[0:2, 1] = 255
mask[1, 2:4] = 255
# mask = array([[  0, 255,   0,   0],
#               [  0, 255, 255, 255],
#               [  0,   0,   0,   0]])

pixels = img[mask != 0]
# pixels = array([1, 5, 6, 7])
```

I want to implement the same functionality in C++ using cv::Mat arrays. I understand this can be done using for loops, but I would prefer a more efficient (vectorized) solution, if one even exists.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750824/best-way-to-indexing-a-matrix-in-opencv

Comment: Nice to see a fellow FE student  ;)
Sadly C++ is a bit more complicated. The most efficient way would be to scan over pixels with pointers. Check that both dimensions match and then go with a for loop and just compare the values at indexes. Iterators might be a bit more easier on the eyes but a bit slower (there is a performance table in the link below). If you want to transform those pixels according to value LUT (lookup table) might also be an interesting solution.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to indexing a matrix in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750824/best-way-to-indexing-a-matrix-in-opencv)

Comment: The links you have attached correspond to masking an image and not to extract only certain pixel values. I have updated my question to hopefully clarify my problem better.

Comment: @MatejJeglič Loops are the fastest way to do this in C++. The tutorial shows you how to scan all pixels in an image, which is what you need to do.

Comment: @Anže, greetings to you as well! I see you have also dive into the field of computer vision.  :)

Comment: @beaker, Thank you for confirming my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through all the image pixels. First of all You can create image with reference image with mask on it:

```
srcImage.copyTo(dstImage, mask);
```

You can now create function to do something on pixels:

```
//Your function
void doSomething(cv::Point3_<uint8_t> &pixel)
{
    //... in this example you can change value like this: pixel.x = 255 - x means first color channel
}
```

Now when You iterate You have to check if pixel is equal zero. In c++ You can iterate in several ways:

```
// .at method: 
// Loop over all rows
for (int r = 0; r < dstImage.rows; r++)
{
    // Loop over all columns
    for (int c = 0; c < dstImage.cols; c++)
    {
        // Obtain pixel
        Point3_<uint8_t> pixel = dstImage.at<Point3_<uint8_t>>(r, c);
        // check if values are zero
        if (pixel.x !=0 && pixel.y !=0 && pixel.z !=0)
        // function
             doSomething(pixel);
        // set result
        dstImage.at<Point3_<uint8_t>>(r, c) = pixel;
    }

}


//with pointers  
// Get pointer to first pixel
Point3_<uint8_t>* pixel = dstImage.ptr<Point3_<uint8_t>>(0, 0);
const Point3_<uint8_t>* endPixel = pixel + dstImage.cols * dstImage.rows;
// Loop over all pixels
for (; pixel != endPixel; pixel++)
{
    // check if values are zero
    if (pixel.x !=0 && pixel.y !=0 && pixel.z !=0)
          doSomething(*pixel);
}


//forEach - utilizes all the cores to apply any function at every pixel - the fastest way
//define Functor
struct Operator
{
    void operator ()(Point3_<uint8_t> &pixel, const int * position) const
    {           
          // check if values are zero
          if (pixel.x !=0 && pixel.y !=0 && pixel.z !=0)
                doSomething(pixel);
    }
};
//execute functor
dstImage.forEach<Point3_<uint8_t>>(Operator());
```

It will works if in reference image there are no zero values before putting mask on it. If they are You have to iterate through mask image with forEach. Then You can use `const int * position` argument `int x = position[0]; int y = position[1];` to check in which coordinates mask pixels are equal 0 and only for them do something on reference image.